# Flutter confusing nested list with object

Tags: flutter, dart

This would work fine in JS, but Dart (Flutter) is having a heart attack. Any idea why ??

```
void main() {
  var foo = [
    {
      "some": "thing",  // comment this line and it works ??
      "test": ["one", "two", "three"]
    }
  ];

  // The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'
  print(foo[0]["test"][0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like below

```
void main() {
  List foo = [
    {
      "some": "thing",  // comment this line and it works ??
      "test": ["one", "two", "three"]
    }
  ];

  // The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'
  print(foo[0]["test"][0]);
}
```